# How to iterate over a nested list that's inside a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, collections

I'm trying to iterate over the 'Resource' key to determine if it satisfies a condition.

I have a use case where I have to iterate over each of the resource keys to determine if it's equal to a particular value. Essentially, I am just validating the policy has the correct permissions.

```
{'Action': ['s3:PutObject', 'kms:GenerateKey'],
'Effect': 'Allow'
'Resource': ['arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:<account_id>:key/*',
'arn:aws:s3:::bucket]}
```

Is there a way I can iterate over each value in the list for **Resource**?

So far I have this

```
for value in policy:
    Resource = value['Resource']
    for resource in Resources:
        if resource == 'arn:aws:s3:::bucket'
        return True
```

However, I just realized this does not work as expected.

Comment: what does not work? you have to provide debug details. In your case there is a typo: you're assigning `Resource` but going through `Resources`

Comment: I think you are missing a ' at the end of  this line 'Resource': ['arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:<account_id>:key/*',
'arn:aws:s3:::bucket]

Comment: there is also a comma missing after `'Allow'` and an indent below your if... You should also remove your first loop and assign `Resources = policy['Resource']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need:

```
for value in policy:
    Resource = value['Resource']
    if 'arn:aws:s3:::bucket' in Resource:
        return True
```

If you still want to iterate through the list:

```
for value in policy:
    Resource = value['Resource']
    for resource in Resource:
        if resource == 'arn:aws:s3:::bucket':
            return True
```

Pls note the typo in your code: `for resource in Resources:` should be `for resource in Resource:` You have added extra **s** in your variable name `Resource`

Comment: Is there also a way to itterate over multiple different resources in this policy that are separate actions?

Comment: You mean get the resource and it's associated action?

Comment: First box seem to have worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the array corresponding to 'Response' key in dictionary and iterate over it.

```
dct = {'Action': ['s3:PutObject', 'kms:GenerateKey'],
'Effect': 'Allow'
'Resource': ['arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:<account_id>:key/*',
'arn:aws:s3:::bucket']}

resource = dct.get('Resource')
for array_element in resource:
    # do stuff as you wish with each array_element
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling you actually want to do this:

```
bucket_policies = [
    each for each in policy 
    if 'arn:aws:s3:::bucket' in each['Resource']
]
```

This will get you a list of the policies in policy that has that key in resource.